# Android - New intent with captured Image

Tags: android, crop, android-camera-intent

I am developing an android app. When I capture an image using the code

`Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture)`

it will be stored in my sdcard as well as it will be displayed in the **ImageView**. Next, on button **‘Crop Picture**’ click event, it should open the captured image as a new intent with the crop feature.
I've code to open the Gallery and select the captured image with the crop feature, but I don’t want the Gallery to get opened, instead I want the captured image in new intent with crop features.

Could anyone please assist?

Comment: I am using c# code not java.

Answer (score 1):

In this case What you should do is, when it goes to next activity, save the image in local device, and put the image location as a intent value. Then when the new activity start, `onCreate` method, get the image location from intent values and load the image from the saved location. then delete the saved image.

If you can wait for few hours, I can put the code here.Feel free to ask anything until you get what you want.

Cheers!!